# VB Script - move files older than 180 days from modified date to another directory

Tags: vbscript

i would like to know if there is a vb script which will move files from a specific location and there subfolders to another location based on their modified date and to keep the original directory structure in the new location.

The results to be saved in a .txt file.

thx in advance.

Comment: This may lead you in the right direction. http://www.safeer.in/2009/09/vb-script-to-move-files-based-on.html

Answer (score 0):

This former question here on SO

[VBScript - copy files modified in last 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004797/vbscript-copy-files-modified-in-last-24-hours)

is a sample from which you can start from. If you have any difficulties to adapt it to your needs, come back and ask again.

Comment: Hello.I dont know how to write script. newbie... :)