# Deleting files with specific names and last modified date vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VB Script, please help me with the below code.

I have a requirement where i need to delete all files in a folder older than x days and file name starting with **xxxyyyzzz.log**.

I have below code, but it is throwing

> error as error in line 16

```
Const strPath = "C:\Users\xyz\Downloads"  
Dim objFSO  
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Call Search (strPath)  

WScript.Echo"Done."

Sub Search(str)  
    Dim objFolder, objSubFolder, objFile
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(str)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If Not ((objFile.filename = xxx*.log) And (objFile.DateCreated < (Now() - x)) Then
            objFile.Delete(True)
        End If

    Next
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Search(objSubFolder.Path)

            If (objSubFolder.Files.Count = 0) Then
            objSubFolder.Delete(True)
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean delete all files with extension .log  and older than x days ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript - copy files modified in last 24 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004797/vbscript-copy-files-modified-in-last-24-hours)

Comment: Where did you get your example from `File` object doesn't have a `Filename` property? As @MikeC point's out there is already a ton of varying examples on [so] on how to do this, we don't need yet another.

Comment: There are several questions on SO (with answers) that will help you go through all files in a folder, filter them by name and date and then do some file operation on them. An example is [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004797/vbscript-copy-files-modified-in-last-24-hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004797/vbscript-copy-files-modified-in-last-24-hours?rq=1) can be a beginning.

Comment: Hi Hackoo, Yes i want to delete all files with name starting xxx*.log and the last modified date is 10 days before.
Hi MikeC and Lankymart, I have tried all the links you gave and was unable to make out what is wrong in my code.

Can you guys please help me to correct the above code.

Comment: Please help me to correct the below statement

  If Not ((objFile.filename = xxx*.log) And (objFile.DateCreated < (Now() - x)) Then
                objFile.Delete(True)
            End If